# How to reduce corruption in developing countries using Ethereum

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, golang, decentralized-exchange

I would like an honest opinion on whether or not the picture below is self-explanatory. I would also like to know what more functionalities I can add to reduce the capital flight by government officials by using Ethereum's unique qualities.

[image]